# Convert Delphi BufferToHex function to Python

Tags: python, delphi

I am just learning Python. Apologies in advance.

I have a Delphi function that creates a string hash.  It first converts a string into an ELF Hash(??) then changes that to a HEX number.

I have the first part working in Python

```
def ELFHash(key):
    hash = 0
    x    = 0
    for i in range(len(key)):
      hash = (hash << 4) + ord(key[i])
      x = hash & 0xF0000000
      if x != 0:
        hash ^= (x >> 24)
      hash &= ~x
    return hash
```

In Delphi an additional step is done which converts it to the Hex value

```
function BufferToHex(const Buf; BufSize : Cardinal) : string;
var
  I     : LongInt;
begin
  Result := '';
  for I := 0 to BufSize - 1 do
    Result := Result + IntToHex(TByteArray(Buf)[I], 2); 
end;
```

buf here is the elf hash i got, stored in a Delphi longint and then BufSize is the Delphi sizeOf() of that longint, which so far seems to return 4.

How would I make a Python function similar to the BufferToHex one that will return an equivalent output? As far as I can tell the python types are different and not returning the same byte size (it seems to return 16 not 4), and when I messed with the ctypes stuff I was still getting different numbers.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're asking to convert a Delphi hash function to Python, but you haven't actually shown the Delphi hash function. All we have is your assessment of the function that determined it's an "Elf" hash. If the part you're having trouble with is how to convert a buffer to hex, then just *ask that* and leave the hash stuff out of it since it has nothing to do with writing buffers in hex.

Comment: well I corrected the title but left the other function as I was trying to show what would be being passed into the new function. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that function does is convert binary to hex string. Since your input hash is 32 bits wide all you need is this:

```
'%08X' % hash
```

where hash is the int that contains the hashed value.

Since I guess that you are on a little endian machine, this will have the hex bytes reversed. Fix that like this:

```
hashstr = '%08X' % hash
hashstr = "".join(reversed([hashstr[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hashstr), 2)]))
```

Put it all together and you have this:

```
def ELFHash(key):
    hash, x = 0, 0
    for i in range(len(key)):
        hash = (hash << 4) + ord(key[i])
        x = hash & 0xF0000000
        if x != 0:
            hash ^= (x >> 24)
            hash &= ~x
    hashstr = '%08X' % hash
    return "".join(reversed([hashstr[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hashstr), 2)]))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I even added in an endian check with sys.byteorder :)